# login via facebook and gmail does not run at a time in page load in single code in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Login via Facebook and Gmail does not run at a time in page load in single code in asp.net c#

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        {
         FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "************";
         FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "**************";


        GoogleConnect.ClientId = "***j.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "********";
        GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
                if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
                {

                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('User has denied access.')", true);
                    return;
                }

                string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
                {
                    string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
                    FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
                    faceBookUser.PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookUser.Id);
                    pnlFaceBookUser.Visible = true;
                    lblId.Text = faceBookUser.Id;
                    lblUserName.Text = faceBookUser.UserName;
                    lblName.Text = faceBookUser.Name;
                    lblEmail.Text = faceBookUser.Email;
                    ProfileImage.ImageUrl = faceBookUser.PictureUrl;
                    btnFacebookLogIn.Enabled = false;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
                {
                    find4 f1 = new find4();
                    var code1 = "UserCode";
                    userCodeId = (code1.ToString() + (f1.find(pr) + 1)).ToString();
                    pr.UserCodeId = userCodeId;
                    code = Request.QueryString["code"];
                    string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code);
                    GoogleProfile profile = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleProfile>(json);
                    string emailid;
                    pr.FirstName = profile.DisplayName;
                    string mail = profile.Emails.Find(email => email.Type == "account").Value;
                    pr.UserEmail = mail;
                    pr.UserImage = profile.Image.Url;
                    DataTable dt = lg.finddublecateemail(pr);
                    emailid = dt.Rows[0]["userEmail"].ToString();
                    if (mail == emailid)
                    {
                        Response.Write("This Email is Alredy Exists..");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lg.registrationOrPersonalDetailsInsertuserlog(pr);
                    }
                    btnGmailLogIn.Enabled = false;
                }
                if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: you should not make your id & secret public here

Comment: Great work Jeff Siver. @Harshili Patel - be aware next time.

Comment: @Harishili Patel, I'd strongly encourage you to change your secrets with both Facebook and Google. Posting them here for even a few minutes is enough for them to be stolen.